# Regex to parse long words

Tags: regex

Need regex to parse long words with 20+ symbols length that can potentially break design. Planning to use ­ for separating word parts.

Comment: my stupid question

/([^\s]{20})/, '\1&shy;'

Answer (score 5):

Try this regular expression:

```
\b\w{20,}
```

Or if the implementation you are using supports [Unicode character properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop):

```
\b\p{L}{20,}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be \w (lower-case W) to match any "word" character? \W will match any "non-word" character.

Answer (score 1):

```
([a-zA-Z]){20,}
```

Comment: Of course it depends of author intentions. Sometimes \w is better, but remember that \w includes digits.