# regex to truncate long words and append ellipses

Tags: php, regex, truncate

This question has effective solutions for identifying long words:
[Regex to parse long words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828869/regex-to-parse-long-words)

How would I then truncate them at a set value and append "..."

Basically, I want to apply a preg_replace on a long string and truncate any very long words (not truncate the entire string -- just the long words).

The regex flavor should be PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**edit:** This works for me

```
$pattern = "/(?<=(\s\w{10}))(\w*\s)/";
```

This pattern effectively matches any word characters characters followed by a space, that were preceded by a space and 10 word characters.

Then just call something like this:

```
preg_replace($pattern,"... ",$string);
```

Hope that helps :)

**edited:** Actually should use `\s` instead of space, this will match any whitespace characters.

Comment: this finds the words > 10 characters, but doesn't truncate/append. what i'm looking for is something that takes: abcdefghijklmnop -> abcdefghij...

Comment: @Brian Edited, `"joop jopjopjopjopjop joop"` returns `joop jopjopjopj... joop` now :)

Comment: closer -- i'm getting an oddity where it only replaces if the string is followed by a line break. and when it replaces, it removes the line break. so:
longwordlongword
longwordlongword
->
longwordlo...longwordlo...

Comment: (there was supposed to be a line break between the two long words -- SO strips the breaks for comments)

Comment: @Brian Hmm, that is very odd indeed. This might sound silly (you probably knew) but make sure the browser doesn't perceive as HTML, thus simply outputting it on one line (make sure to check source) because for me, it works perfectly... _edit: BTW; ran on PHP 5.3.4_

Comment: i think the problem is that my long-word could be the entire string, or it could be a word within a longer set of words. the above requires a leading/trailing space. i need it to define a word that way OR as the full string value.

Comment: Instead of the leading and trailing space which I had first, I put in `\s`, which matches spaces as well as newlines and tabs, so that it would work on multi-line strings as well. No, this won't match the entire string because I explicitly used `\w`. Just to make sure, I updated the answer a couple of times, do you really have the latest pattern I provided?

Oh, and you might wanna double-escape the `\s` and `\w` like this: `\\s` (I don't know if that makes a significant difference though)

Answer (score 2):

I guess this regular expression does the trick.
I tested using php 5.3.6 and worked fine.

```
$pattern = "/(\\b\\w{10})\\w+\\b/";
echo preg_replace($pattern, "$1...", "pequeno palavramedia palavrabemgrandemesmo\n");
```

Where is `{10}` you should replace by the maximum allowed size without replacement. If you want a maximum word size of N, you should use `{N-3}`, because of the length of the dots.

It should run fine for big strings, because it describe a regular language and the running time should be O(n). Of course, it depends on the implementation of regex.